# Can't access colum value in QSqlQueryModel

Tags: qt5, qtreeview

i have some problem with changing value in QTableView cell.

```
ui->search_results->show();
int num = model->rowCount();
for (int i = 0; i<num; i++) {
    QSqlRecord rec = model->record(i);
    QString file_chron = rec.value(1).toString();
    QString file_age = get_file_agestring_from_chron(file_chron);
    //model->setData(model->index(i,1), QVariant(file_age), Qt::EditRole);
    rec.setValue(1,file_age);
```

it seems that both functions work as they should in a loop

```
    qDebug()<<rec.value(1).toString()+" "+rec.value(2).toString()+" "+rec.value(3).toString()+" "+rec.value(4).toString()+" "+rec.value(5).toString();
}
```

but outside we have old value.

```
qDebug()<<model->data(model->index(3,1)).toString();
ui->search_results->setModel(model);
ui->search_results->hideColumn(4);
```

i need to reimplement value inside this field.

I think that it is access error, but i can't understand how to set new value!

sorry, i can't add tag QSqlQueryModel

Comment: Solution: use SqlTableModel, because SqlQueryModel is read-only

Answer (score 0):

You are operation on QSqlRecord rec; which is **copy** of the record instead of the reference to it. As for setting data - see model : setData function